# I created an object in with a for loop, inside a function, but get error in print object not found when trying to print it

Tags: r

I've created an object obs in the loop shown below and the loop returns obs. However when I try to print obs i get the message that obs is not found. I'm new to programming R and I'm lost. I've tried googling the problem and have not found a answer.

```
complete<-function(directory,ID){
files_list <- list.files( directory , full.names=TRUE) #creates a list of files
dat <- data.frame() #creates an empty data frame
for (i in 1:332) { #loops through the files, rbinding them together
  dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
}
cleandat<-na.omit(dat)
obs<-c()
for(i in ID){
  n<-nrow(cleandat[cleandat$ID %in% i,])

  obs<-append(obs,n)
}

return(obs)
}
complete("specdata", ID<-c(2,4,8,10,12))

[1] 1041  474  192  148   96

print(obs)
Error in print(obs) : object 'obs' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects defined in a function are not available outside the function. If you return a value from a function, you must store the result somewhere. Try

```
obs <- complete("specdata", ID<-c(2,4,8,10,12))
print(obs)
```

This prevents you from having to know the name of variables inside function that you may not have written yourself.